# Laravel FPDI Package but Output Method is undefined

Tags: php, laravel, class, fpdi

currently figured out how to implement the FPDI Class from https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v2/ into my laravel project.
Now I think I can execute some of the method, but currently getting undefined method for the most important one:

```
    $pdf2 = new Fpdi();
    $path2 = public_path() . '/storage/Template/testpdf3.pdf';
    $pdf2->setSourceFile($path2);
    $tplIdx = $pdf2->importPage(1);
    $pdf2->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);
    $pdf2->Output(); -> this one getting undefined Method.
```

The other method are all okay. Do you have any Idea? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the method is working. Do you have any idea why VSC is showing me this error?

Comment: Which plugin are you using on vscode? Also, can you  install **laravel-ide-helper** (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and running `php artisan ide-helper:generate` command?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Which plugin are you using on vscode? Also, can you install laravel-ide-helper (github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and running php artisan ide-helper:generate